# How can I cast an NSMutableArray to a Swift array of a specific type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am migrating my iOS project to Swift. I am doing this class by class. When I call Objective C methods from Swift, a lot of Objective C types are converted to their Swift counterparts.

In my case an Objective C `NSMutableArray` gets converted to Swift's `Array<AnyObject>`. Now here comes my problem. Within my Swift class, I get such an array back from an Objective C object. Now that I am in the Swift world, I would like to cast this array to a specific type instead of `AnyObject`, because I know for sure what kind of objects exist in this array.

The compiler won't let me do that! Let me simplify my problem by saying I want to cast to an array containing strings. This is what I tried:

```
var strings = myObjcObject.getStrings() as [String]
```

I get the following error from the compiler:

> 'String' is not identical to 'AnyObject'

I would have to agree with the compiler, since String is indeed not identical to AnyObject. But I don't see why that is a problem. I can downcast AnyObject to String if I want, right?

I also tried:

```
var strings = myObjcObject.getStrings() as? [String]
```

This seems to be a step in the right direction, but getStrings() returns an `NSMutableArray` so I get the following error:

> 'NSArray' is not a subtype of 'NSMutableArray'

Is there any way to do what I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can make this work with a double downcast, first to `NSArray`, then to `[String]`:

```
var strings = myObjcObject.getStrings() as NSArray as [String]
```

Tested in a Playground with:

```
import Foundation

var objCMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: ["a", "b", "c"])
var swiftArray = objCMutableArray as NSArray as [String]
```

***Update:***

In later versions of Swift (at least 1.2), the compiler will complain about `as [String]`. Instead you should use an `if let` with a conditional downcast `as?`:

```
import Foundation

var objCMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: ["a", "b", "c"])
if let swiftArray = objCMutableArray as NSArray as? [String] {
    // Use swiftArray here
}
```

If you are ***absolutely*** sure that your `NSMutableArray` can be cast to `[String]`, then you can use `as!` instead (but you probably shouldn't use this in most cases):

```
import Foundation

var objCMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: ["a", "b", "c"])
var swiftArray = objCMutableArray as NSArray as! [String]
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear and precise answer to my problem! It works now!

Comment: I used this to fix my problem with GestureRecognizers as well. `var arrayOfGestureRecognizers: [UIGestureRecognizer] = self.topViewController.view.gestureRecognizers! as NSArray as [UIGestureRecognizer]` thank you!

Comment: @Mike, could you update your answer with `NSArray as! [String]` for Swift 1.2?

Comment: I would also like to note that in the ObjC source, you can add the necessary generic types to the objc property. Which in my opinion, is much cleaner than doing all this casting.

Comment: @theMonster Does not work for NSMutableArray yet (only for NSArray), think I saw talks of it for Swift 3..

Comment: Probably I will never love Swift... 

Comment: In most cases I am perfectly sure I have typed objective c array so why not to use that '!' and play with optionals ?

Answer (score 37):

`compactMap` is your friend in Swift 4.1 and above, as well as in Swift 3.3-3.4 for that matter.  This means that you don't have any double or forced casting.

```
let mutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: ["a", "b", "c"])
let swiftArray: [String] = mutableArray.compactMap { $0 as? String }
```

---

In previous versions of Swift, 2.0-3.2 and 4.0, you'll want to use `flatMap` for this purpose.  The usage is the same as `compactMap`:

```
let swiftArray: [String] = mutableArray.flatMap { $0 as? String }
```

Comment: This has the advantage that, even if the array can not be cast **as a whole** because **some** of the elements it contains are **not** of type `String`/`NSString`, the "compatible" elements can still be salvaged.

Answer (score 5):

With Swift 1.2 the following will work:

```
let mutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: ["a", "b", "c"])
let swiftArray = NSArray(array: mutableArray) as? [String]
```

Comment: When I try this with Swift 1.2 I get: 'NSMutableArray' is not convertible to '[AnyObject]'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

Answer (score 5):

```
let mutableArray = NSMutableArray()

mutableArray.add("Abc")
mutableArray.add("def")
mutableArray.add("ghi")

if let array = mutableArray as? [String] {
    print(array)    // ["Abc", "def", "ghi"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in Xcode 6.3 i used the following:

```
var mutableArray = NSMutableArray(array:"1", "2", "3")
let swiftArray = mutableArray as AnyObject as! [String]
```

Answer (score 1):

for swift 3

you may consider the following code

```
let array: [String] = nsMutableArrayObject.copy() as! [String]
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case compiler wanted me to write it like this to suppress all warnings and compilation problems, so not just that exclamation marks even if field imagesField is already declared with one, but also parentheses and "as!" to make it sure that nobody complains.

```
(imagesField!.images as! [UIImage])
```

It made me quite uncomfortable... Swift could be nicer, its new language so... I made extension:

```
 public static func cast(_ object: Any) -> Self {
        return object as! Self
    }
```

Assigned it to Array:

```
extension Array: CSLang {
}
```

And now I can write the same statement like this with the same effect:

```
[UIImage].cast(imagesField.images)
```

Like it or not, this is my way, less question and exclamation marks, better. I made also unit test:

```
func testCast() {
    let array: NSMutableArray? = NSMutableArray()
    array?.add("test string 1")
    array?.add("test string 2")
    let stringArray: [String] = [String].cast(array)
    XCTAssertEqual("test string 2", stringArray[1])
}
```