# Using NSMutableArray sortUsingFunction in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray

This [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingFunction:context:) tells you what your sorting function has to look like, but I just can't make a Swift function look like that.

Here's my call:

```
packetsArray.sortUsingFunction(comparePacketDates, context: nil)
```

Here's my function, and I've tried a zillion other variations of it:

```
static func comparePacketDates(packet1 : AnyObject, packet2: AnyObject, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Int {
```

And I've tried using a c function instead, this and a few other variations:

```
NSInteger comparePacketDates(id packet1, id packet2, void* dummy);
```

It's always "cannot invoke with argument list ..." saying the function isn't what's expected as the first argument.

Does anyone have example code of a Swift function that would be accepted as the first argument of the Swift sortUsingFunction?  Or even a c function that would be accepted as the first argument of the **Swift** SortUsingFunction?

Comment: I think the body of your swift comparePacketDates function is missing. That might be helpful in diagnosing the problem. Also, you might consider just casting the NSMutableArray to a Swift array and using Swift's sorting mechanisms. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837539/how-can-i-cast-an-nsmutablearray-to-a-swift-array-of-a-specific-type

Comment: The body of my comparePacketDates doesn't matter, because it's not getting that far.  It won't accept the way I've declared it as the first argument in sortUsingFunction.  Also if I did caste it to a Swift Array does Swift's sort work for an array of custom objects?  Or does it just sort arrays of strings and numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sortUsingComparator`. It's simpler than `sortUsingFunction`. Here's the syntax:

```
a.sortUsingComparator {
    let packet1 = $0 as! Packet
    let packet2 = $1 as! Packet
    if packet1.timestamp < packet2.timestamp {
        return .OrderedAscending
    }
    if packet1.timestamp == packet2.timestamp {
        return .OrderedSame
    }
    return .OrderedDescending
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for your reference that I wrote:

```
var ma = NSMutableArray()

ma.addObject("Hi")
ma.addObject("Anil")

func comp(first: AnyObject, second:AnyObject,  context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Int {
  let f:String  = first as! String
  let s:String = second as! String

  if f > s {
    return 1
  }
  else if ( f == s ) {
    return 0
  }

  return -1

}

ma.sortUsingFunction(comp, context:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(bitPattern: 0))
```

HTH, as a reference to you. Note: I am in Xcode 7.1 Swift 2.1.

Comment: This did not work using what I have: XCode 6.4 / Swift 1.2.  Same old "cannot invoke".  Maybe it's time I upgraded.

Comment: I'll bet your solution works in Swift 2.1 but I cannot test it for a while as I was going to upgrade in 2 weeks.  I don't normally like the "do it a different way" answers, but rob mayor's solution is working for me so I have to accept his answer.  Thx a lot though.