# Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableArray' to expected argument type '[SKTexture]'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I get an error with the following code:

```
func prepareAnimationForDictionary(settings: NSDictionary,repeated: Bool) -> SKAction {
        let atlas: SKTextureAtlas = 
          SKTextureAtlas(named: settings["AtlasFileName"] as! String)
        let textureNames:NSArray = settings["Frames"] as! NSArray
        let texturePack: NSMutableArray = []

        for texPath in textureNames {
            texturePack.addObject(atlas.textureNamed(texPath as! String))
        }

        let timePerFrame: NSTimeInterval = Double(1.0/(settings["FPS"] 
         as! Float))

        let anim:SKAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(texturePack, 
          timePerFrame: timePerFrame) // the error I get is here
        if repeated {
        return SKAction.repeatActionForever(anim)
        }else{
        return anim
        }
```

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837539/how-can-i-cast-an-nsmutablearray-to-a-swift-array-of-a-specific-type#25837720

Answer (score 3):

Just use the expected (Swift) types

```
...
let textureNames = settings["Frames"] as! [String]
var texturePack =  [SKTexture]()

for texPath in textureNames {
    texturePack.append(atlas.textureNamed(texPath))
}
...
```

From the Swift point of view the mutable Foundation collection types `NSMutableArray` and `NSMutableDictionary` are type unspecified and are not related to the Swift native counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

Change `timePerFrame`
to `(timePerFrame as [AnyObject]) as! [SKTexture]`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, think about this. You have a variable `texturePack`. You don't show the declaration, but based on the error message, I'm going to assume it's of type `NSMutableArray`. The call in question wants an array of `SKTexture` objects.

So, cast your `texturePack` to the required type:

```
let anim:SKAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(texturePack as! [SKTexture], 
  timePerFrame: timePerFrame) //error i get is here
```

Note that if there is any chance that texturePack is not an array of `SKTexture` objects, you would be better off using `if let` or `guard` to check that the cast succeeds:

```
guard 
  let anim:SKAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(texturePack as! [SKTexture], 
    timePerFrame: timePerFrame) //error i get is here
else
{
  return nil;
}
```

Or, as the others have suggested, change the declaration of your `texturePack` array to be of type `[SKTexture]`

Comment: This is correct, but there's no need for `texturePack` to be `NSMutableArray` instead of a swift `Array`

Comment: At first I did not see the declaration of the array in the code the OP posted, so I figured there might be a valid reason for the array to be an NSMutableArray rather than a Swift typed array. If you can make the array a Swift array of `SKTexture` objects it's certainly better. (or for that matter you could use the new typed NSArray constructs.)

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. Much appreciated